# How to use JavaScript/jQuery "this" keyword to toggle rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, toggle

I have a form that will post data to a table and will separate the data into two rows, a row-header and a row-body (similar to bootstrap accordion card-header and card-body). Initially, whenever I click on a button it toggles both row-bodies. Now, it's now only toggling the first row body.

How do you use the `this` keyword so that when I click on `button1` on `row-header1`, it toggles `row-body1`, and `button2` on `row-header2` toggles `row-body2`?

This is the code I'm actually working with, but it contains ejs:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th>Award</th>
    <th>Fee</th>
    <th>#Copies</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>More Info</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!--Row header-->
  <tr id="table-header">
    <% awards.forEach(function(award){ %>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
    <td><%= award.deadline %></td>
    <td><%= award.awdname %></td>
    <td>$<%= award.fee %></td>
    <td><%= award.copies %></td>
    <td><%= award.genre %></td>
    <td><button id="moreInfo">Click Me</i></button></td>

  <!--Row body    -->
  <tr id="table-body">
    <td colspan="7">
      <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description:</label> <%= award.desc %></div>
      <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Sponsored by:</label> <%= award.sponsor %></div>
      <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Prize: $</label><%= award.prize %></div>
      <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Shipping status:</label> <%= award.postorarrive %></div>
      <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Website:</label> <%= award.url %></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><% }); %></tr>               
</tbody>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#table-body").hide();

$("#moreInfo").on("click", function() {
    $("#table-body").toggle();
});
```

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjs13/kaxocr7h/) for a modified version of the above code but without ejs.

I've spent days looking at similar questions and trying to adapt the given answers to my scenario but with no success.

Comment: the problem is from your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjs13/kaxocr7h/) is that your assigning same ids to different elements which is just wrong

Comment: TJS13  did you checked answer

Comment: Thanks for the note, kellymandem. Initially I didn't have any ids only classes I must have accidentally left it in when I was looking through previous SO asks and trying to adapt it to my scenario. I'll remember to treat ids with caution going forward.

Comment: Can someone clarify the difference between Gokul Maha's $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle() versus Alive or Die's   $(this).closest('tr').next(".table-body").toggle();
Both works but is one more preferable or cleaner than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `id` as a selector for multiple buttons, because every element, in order to be properly selected by `id` should be unique, and thus selected one by one. For common functionality, when multiple similar elements to be selected `class` should be used instead.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Row#</td>
            <th><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <!--Row header-->
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
            <td>Row1 Content1</td>
            <td>R1C2</td>
            <td>R1C3</td>
            <td><button class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        <!--Row body   -->
        <tr class="table-body">
            <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="showContent"><label for="">Description1:</label></div>  
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
            <td>Row2 Content1</td>
            <td>R2C2</td>
            <td>R2C3</td>
            <td><button class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        <!--Row body   -->
        <tr class="table-body">
            <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="showContent"><label for="">Description2:</label></div>  
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>

$(".table-body").hide();
$(".moreInfo").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaxocr7h/1/

Comment: please note that, `id` should be unique for element.

Comment: THANK YOU! This works not only in the jsfiddle but also my actual .ejs code!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".table-body").hide();
$(document).on("click", ".moreInfo", function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->


<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Row#</td>
            <th><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <!--Row header-->
        <tr id="table-header">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
            <td>Row1 Content1</td>
            <td>R1C2</td>
            <td>R1C3</td>
            <td><button id="moreInfo" class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <!--Row body   -->
        <tr id="table-body" class="table-body">
            <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description1:</label></div>  
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr id="table-header">
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
            <td>Row2 Content1</td>
            <td>R2C2</td>
            <td>R2C3</td>
            <td><button id="moreInfo"  class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
        </tr>
        
        
        <!--Row body   -->
        <tr id="table-body" class="table-body">
            <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description2:</label></div>  
            </td>
        </tr>
                 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add a class for moreInfo button and the table row that have to be toggled

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Row#</td>
                <th><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></th>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <!--Row header-->
            <tr id="table-header">
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td>Row1 Content1</td>
                <td>R1C2</td>
                <td>R1C3</td>
                <td><button id="moreInfo" class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
            </tr>

            <!--Row body   -->
            <tr id="table-body" class="table-body">
                <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description1:</label></div>  
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="table-header">
                <td>2</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td>Row2 Content1</td>
                <td>R2C2</td>
                <td>R2C3</td>
                <td><button id="moreInfo"  class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td> 
            </tr>


            <!--Row body   -->
            <tr id="table-body" class="table-body">
                <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description2:</label></div>  
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>






    $(".table-body").hide();
$(document).on("click", ".moreInfo", function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`id` should be unique, Look into below code with `class` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table-body").hide();
  $(".moreInfo").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next(".table-body").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Row#</td>
      <th><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></th>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!--Row header-->
    <tr id="table-header">
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
      <td>Row1 Content1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
      <td>R1C3</td>
      <td><button class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td>
    </tr>

    <!--Row body   -->
    <tr class="table-body">
      <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
        <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description1:</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="table-header">
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
      <td>Row2 Content1</td>
      <td>R2C2</td>
      <td>R2C3</td>
      <td><button class="moreInfo">Click Me</button></td>
    </tr>


    <!--Row body   -->
    <tr class="table-body">
      <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
        <div class="showContent hide"><label for="">Description2:</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```