# How to delete mulitple rows on click of a button

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, button

I want to delete the selected row on click of my delete button. My delete functionality is working fine the problem I am facing is only top most delete button is working my UI screen looks like below
[image]

I select the table rows using the checkboxes. If I select all three records all three delete button should work and any delete button can delete the selected rows but in my case only first delete button is working.
This is my html and js code.

```
<td class="td-org">${entry.sORGID}</td>
<td class="td-org">${entry.url}</td>
<td class="td-org">${entry.type}</td>
<td class="td-org"><a href="" onclick="testing("")" />Testing</td>
<td class="td-org"><input type="button" value="Delete" id="btntest" />

document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function(){
      var selchbox = getSelectedChbox(this.form);     // gets the array returned by getSelectedChbox()
    var myvalue = JSON.stringify(selchbox);
     //document.write("check check"+selchbox);
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/delete",
            dataType : "JSON",
            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(selchbox),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                         alert("SUCCESS!!!");
                     },
                     error: function (args) {
                         alert("Error on ajax post");
                     }

        });
      //alert(selchbox);
    }
```

getSelectedChbox code

```
function getSelectedChbox(ele) {
  var selchbox = [];        // array that will store the value of selected checkboxes

  // gets all the input tags in frm, and their number
  var inpfields = ele.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;

  // traverse the inpfields elements, and adds the value of selected (checked) checkbox in selchbox

  for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
    //selchbox = JSON.stringify({'selchbox' : selchbox});


  }

  return selchbox;
}
```

In controller i am performing delete

What i am missing here?

Comment: post getSelectedChbox method and the backend code where you are deleting the array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding event with `id` which happens to be unique, hence, click event will work for only 1 element.

To solve this you can add class to the `delete` buttons. And iterate over them to bind the `onclick` event.

**HTML**

```
<td class="td-org"><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete-btn" />
```

**JS**

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn');
for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
   let btn= btns[i];
   btn.onclick = function() {
       // your code
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can have a function in your script and have `onclick` in your html for the same.

**HTML**

```
<td class="td-org"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use **id** as a selector for multiple buttons, because every element, in order to be properly selected by id should be unique, and thus selected one by one. For common functionality, when multiple similar elements to be selected **class** should be used instead.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076572/how-to-use-javascript-jquery-this-keyword-to-toggle-rows/53076717#53076717)